# NSDictionary shows nil in IOS/ Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I am receiving an arabic data through web service. I get data as a JSON object, but when I pass the value to an `NSDictionary` it shows `nil` and am not able to get `key/pair` value.i receive value till `data`,but i cant pass that to `NSDictionary`.

Here is the code:

```
(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
         NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];


    for (NSString *key in [json allKeys])
    {

        NSArray *feed = [json objectForKey:key];

        for(int i=0; i<feed.count;i++)
        {
            for (NSString *key1 in [[feed objectAtIndex:i] allKeys])
            {
                if([key1 isEqualToString:@"newsTitle"])
                {
                    NSString *value = [[feed objectAtIndex:i]  objectForKey:key1];
                    [NewsTitleArray addObject:value];

                }
                else if([key1 isEqualToString:@"newsDescription"])
                {
                    NSString *value = [[feed objectAtIndex:i]  objectForKey:key1];
                    [NewsDescriptionArray addObject:value];

                }}}}
```

Comment: Is it possible that the JSON value you're receiving from the server isn't a dictionary or maybe contains additional characters which make it an invalid JSON string? Can you please also include the JSON string received from the server?

Comment: @Chonch  i check the string  using jsonlint.com/ ..and it say it is is validate JSON..thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use proper encoding for your data, normally arabic content require `ISO-Latin` encoding. Though your code is wrong, you need to use correct NSURLConnection Delegate function to get complete data, you are trying to parse the incomplete data

See the changes below

**Declare a variable**

```
NSMutableData *receivedData;
```

**Handle the delegate calls**

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

//This delegate function gets called multiple times while fetching the data..

      if(!receivedData){
           receivedData=[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:data];
      }else{
           [receivedData appendData:data];
      }

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    //When the connection completes the processing, do you parsing

    if(receivedData.length>0){
      NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];

      NSData *utf8Data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

      NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:utf8Data options:kNilOptions error:nil];


     for (NSString *key in [json allKeys])
    {

        NSArray *feed = [json objectForKey:key];

        for(int i=0; i<feed.count;i++)
        {
            for (NSString *key1 in [[feed objectAtIndex:i] allKeys])
            {
                if([key1 isEqualToString:@"newsTitle"])
                {
                    NSString *value = [[feed objectAtIndex:i]  objectForKey:key1];
                    [NewsTitleArray addObject:value];

                }
                else if([key1 isEqualToString:@"newsDescription"])
                {
                    NSString *value = [[feed objectAtIndex:i]  objectForKey:key1];
                    [NewsDescriptionArray addObject:value];

                }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

**Note: The code above is not tested, might not work at first go, but it should be this way.**

I hope it helps.

Cheers.

Comment: can i use same code for english? or do i need to change anthing in `encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]`,my app take english and arabic as well

Comment: @jithinvarghese If the data is mix of both, use ISO, else you don't need that conversion you can directly use it.

Comment: @ iphonic am using two web service one for arabic data and other one is for english data..,,when i click arabic button it will call arabic web service, and when i click english it will call english web service,so my question is can i use  same code for both ?thank you

Comment: @jithinvarghese Yes, I think it should work, as in English there won't be any character that needs to be converted for ISO-Latin, thus no conversion will occur, and code should work.